# How to use A4988 microstepping?

Tags: arduino, driver, stepper-motor

Can I connect MS1, MS2, M3 to GND to use the microstepping function?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it can be answered trivially by reading the datasheet.

Comment: You are smart...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, connecting MS1, MS2, MS3 low will **NOT** enable micro stepping.

If you look at the datasheet for the [A4988](http://www.allegromicro.com/~/media/Files/Datasheets/A4988-Datasheet.ashx?la=en) you will find all the information you need.

Table 2 shows how the select lines should be set for whatever level if microstepping you require:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. But why is CNC V4 using the GND for the MS pins?

Comment: The documentation on the KeyStudio CNC v4.0 is not great, but here's a link to someone building the V3.0 board: http://blog.protoneer.co.nz/arduino-cnc-shield-v3-00-assembly-guide/ ....the jumpers are identical on both. I assume they provide you with all three jumpers loaded so you have them. You have to decide whether you want to microstep or not. From what I see here, all three jumpers in place is Full Step. Try it out....you won't blow it up.

Comment: Thanks Jack. Now I think V4 is a mess, because the back face of the PCB is using GND for microstepping.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your comment. The MSx pins are pulled high internally on the A4988, you insert the option pin (which connects to Gnd) to pull it low.